# Recuperar archivos

Tags: git, github

tengo un proyecto al cual le inicie git, y despues le di un `git add .`
pero cuando lo hice me di cuenta de que habia añadido hasta los modulos de node, entonces fui a la parte donde dice staged changes en VS Code y le di a Discard changes y elimine los archivos sin querer, no se si exista alguna manera de recuperarlos pues no aparece ni en papelera, muchas gracias de antemano, es la primera vez que me pasa esto y no se hacer y estoy preocupado porque borre todo, de nuevo gracias de antemano.

Edit:
Este fue la advertencia que me salio, y pues por lo que dice no se si pueda recuperar los archivos]

[[image: 1]

Comment: :-( Parece que el mensaje te lo dejaba claro...

Comment: @abufalia Claro le di sin leer y pues paso lo que paso x,D

Answer (score 0):

Si yo fuera tu, lo primero que haría sería un backup del repositorio por si acaso:

```
tar zcvf .git ../backup.git.gz
```

Primero, la buena noticia: Si los archivos fueron agregados al index, entonces los objetos (archivos y directorios) están en la base de datos de git y se pueden recuperar (a menos que se haya hecho un `git gc`). Segundo, la mala noticia: Los tienes que buscar manualmente.

Los objetos "dangling" (o sea, que nadie los apunte) los puedes ver con `git fsck`. Esto va a listar archivos y *àrboles* (o sea, directorios) sin distinción. Con esa lista de objetos puedes ver el contenido de cada uno (con `git cat-file -p id-del-objeto`) para entonces proceder a hacerle un `git restore` a los que estaban en la raiz de tu proyecto.

Mucha suerte!

PS Como tip adicional: cuando ya has agregado al index y quieres sacar algo, la forma de hacerlo es con `git reset`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, aunque al final parece que si se borro definitivamente y ni siquiera alcance a hacer un commit ni nada, ni siquiera con recuva pude recuperar los archivos, si hubiese sabido antes de darle al boton que era solo poner un .gitignore y ya, pero bueno, muchas gracias por la respuesta y espero que no me vuelva a pasar <3